# What does include EnumeratedType and DomainModel means in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include

I came across few ruby codes and found that some class  structures are like

```
module A
  module B
    class C
      include EnumeratedType
         declare :an,      :value => 1,  :description => "AN", 
         declare :bn,      :value => 1,  :description => "BN"
    end
  end
end
```

Similarly I have noticed like `include DomainModel`.

Also I have seen that there is no name field but it seems we can use "declare" key as "name" key when retreiving above as map. Is it so ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `include` keyword means that, it lets you `mix-in` instance methods from the module with the same name as the parameter. In your case, the `include EnumeratedType` means that somewhere in your application or Gem, has a module named `EnumeratedType` and you want to use its instance methods in `class C`

Same with `include DomainModel`.

Comment: thanks..is it so that we can use declare as "name" in C.map ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `declare as name in C.map`?